# ::first-line pseudo element (not appearing)

Tags: jquery, css

I have this following code:

```
   <div id="slide1">            
   <span id="tf1">BUILDING WEBSITES<br>BLABLABLABLA</span>
   </div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#tf1 {
color: #505050; 
text-shadow: #a8a8a8 -2px 1px 0px; 
font-size: 40px; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#tf1::first-line {
color: #FFFFFF; 
text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px; 
font-size: 60px; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#slide1 {
position: absolute; 
padding: 20px; 
width: 700px;
}
```

Everything seems fine to me; except the fact that ::first-line is not appearing and everything is appearing as coded in the #tf1 section in my CSS code.

Any ideas of what is overriding this? or if there is a bug in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#tf1 {
    display: block;
}
```

since `span` has default `display: inline` style and from the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line)** about `::first-line`:

> A first line has only meaning in a block-container box, therefore the
>   ::first-line pseudo-element has only an effect on elements with a
>   display value of block, inline-block, table-cell or table-caption. In
>   all other cases, ::first-line has no effect.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fBmp/2/)**

Comment: Alternatively, use `div` instead of `span`. There does not seem to be any good reason to use `span` here.

Answer (score 2):

`::first-line` only works with block style elements. a `span` is by default inline, so the entire thing is "one line", as in, it's one continuous line that just keeps going on and on and wraps when it meets a boundary.

You can set the `span` to `display: block;` to get `::first-line` to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/hwmWv/

```
#tf1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This pseudo-element only works on block-level elements (when display is set to either block, inline-block, table-caption, table-cell). If set on an inline element, nothing happens, even if that inline element has a line break within it.

```
#tf1 {
color: #505050; 
text-shadow: #a8a8a8 -2px 1px 0px; 
font-size: 40px; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
display: block; /* assign display property value*/
}
```

[source](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/)